# saving/retrieving arraylist to/from SharedPreference with kotlin error "java.lang.NullPointerException: gson.fromJson(json, type) must not be null"

Tags: android, kotlin, sharedpreferences

I am trying to setup saving and retrieving an arrayList of objects to and from sharedPreferences in a fragment and I keep getting the error above. This is my code snippet

```
fun getData() {
    val sharedPreferences = activityCast().getSharedPreferences("DATA", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    val gson = Gson()
    val json = sharedPreferences.getString("data", null)
    val type: Type = object : TypeToken<ArrayList<Car>>(){}.type


    carsList = gson.fromJson(json, type)

    if (carsList.isEmpty()){
        carsList = ArrayList()
    }

}


fun saveBillData(car: Car){
    val sharedPreferences = activityCast().getSharedPreferences("DATA", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    val editor = sharedPreferences.edit()
    val gson = Gson()

    carsList.add(car)

    val json: String = gson.toJson(carsList)

    editor.putString("data", json)

   editor.apply

}
```

I looked up the error and I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69433395/java-lang-nullpointerexception-gson-fromjsonplacejson-placeclass-java-mu)

what I got from that is to change the sharedPreference.getString second argument from null to "{}"

Doing that gives the error:

com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $

Answer (score 0):

BEGIN_OBJECT in JSON is {
BEGIN_ARRAY is [

You are trying to parse a list. So in the case that you don't have any data you want to have it return an empty list, which is "[]". So instead of "{}" you should use "[]"

Comment: Oh, right there... That fixed it. Thank you :)